# Why is my while/switch doing one case twice?

Tags: java

For some reason, if one of the three possible scenarios of my switch stmt is triggered, it is performed twice. The 3 possibilities are Gone, Unlocked, Locked. If "Locked" is triggered, it runs both the Locked and Unlocked "paths".

My code is below and the behavior is in attached screenshot. Am I not understanding how the switch evaluates the value? (I.e. is it a "contains" and not "equals" check?)

```
            while (graveData.next()) {

                switch(graveData.getString("Status")) {
                case "Gone":
                    new FancyMessage("ID").color(GRAY)
                    .then("" + graveData.getInt("ID")).color(AQUA)
                    .then(" ").color(GRAY)
                    .then(graveData.getString("Status"))
                    .color(GREEN).then(", Owner ").color(GRAY)
                    .then(graveData.getString("PlayerName"))
                    .color(YELLOW).then(", Looter ").color(GRAY)
                    .then(graveData.getString("LooterName"))
                    .color(YELLOW).then(", ").color(GRAY)
                    .then("Loc").color(GRAY)
                    .tooltip(graveData.getString("Location"))
                    .send(commandSender);
                    break;
                case "Locked":
                    new FancyMessage("ID").color(GRAY)
                    .then("" + graveData.getInt("ID")).color(AQUA)
                    .then(" ").color(GRAY)
                    .then(graveData.getString("Status"))
                    .color(YELLOW).then(", Owner ").color(GRAY)
                    .then(graveData.getString("PlayerName"))
                    .color(YELLOW).then(", ").color(GRAY)
                    .then("Loc").color(GRAY)
                    .tooltip(graveData.getString("Location"))
                    .send(commandSender);
                case "Unlocked":
                    new FancyMessage("ID").color(GRAY)
                    .then("" + graveData.getInt("ID")).color(AQUA)
                    .then(" ").color(GRAY)
                    .then(graveData.getString("Status"))
                    .color(RED).then(", Owner ").color(GRAY)
                    .then(graveData.getString("PlayerName"))
                    .color(YELLOW).then(", ").color(GRAY)
                    .then("Loc").color(GRAY)
                    .tooltip(graveData.getString("Location"))
                    .send(commandSender);
                    break;
                }
```

[image]

Comment: There's no `break;` for`"Locked" case.

Comment: Unrelated, but please consider a refactoring or three.

Comment: What is your expected behavior?

Comment: @DaveNewton - What do you mean?

Comment: @runelynx I mean you have very similar code in three places, it's very hard to read and think about, and willl be difficult to maintain. It also looks ripe for an enum, and/or there's missing classes or decorators (if the only differences are in output, perhaps decorator). Big chunks of almost-identical code are a smell indicating missing method(s). Big chunks of conditionals are a smell indicating missing class(es).

Comment: @DaveNewton Very helpful on those "smell" indicators, thank you! I think if you saw some of my other classes you'd probably fall out of your chair... and not in a good way ;) Time to do some... "refactoring" I guess! Doesn't sound like fun but my minecraft plugin is starting to get very large and I guess it's going to be harder to maintain if I don't clean up :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need

```
    break;
case "Unlocked":
```

to stop the "[fall through](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)"

`break` is how every case section should end unless you want to automatically run the next one as well.  This is a very powerful and often confusing feature of switch statements.  One that would be easier to spot and understand in your code if you took Dave Newtons advise and refactored.  Consider making `gone()`, `lock()` and `unlock()` methods or even classes each with a `setStatus()` method.  Remove duplication with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense on the refactoring - thank you for the heads up!!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put a break after the `Locked` case. .So it is executing the next case

From [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

> The **break** statements are necessary because without them, statements
>   in switch blocks **fall through:** All statements after the matching case
>   label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of
>   subsequent case labels

Answer (score 1):

After the second `case` (`"locked"`), you forgot to put a `break;` statement. It should look like this :

```
case "Locked":
  new FancyMessage("ID").color(GRAY)
  .then("" + graveData.getInt("ID")).color(AQUA)

        [...]   

  .send(commandSender);
  break; //important !

case "Unlocked":
  new FancyMessage("ID").color(GRAY)
        [...]
```

See also [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for an explanation of `switch` statement *fall-through*.